# php json_encode in Go

Tags: php, go

in php I have this:

```
<?php
    $x = array(1,2,3,4);
    $y = json_encode($x);
    echo $y;
?>
```

which its result is:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

in Go when i use `json.Marshal()` or `jsonEncoder` encode method the result is:

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

which is not equivalent as the json_encode() result in php and I can't decode it in php.

Is there anyway to reach [1, 2, 3, 4] encoded result in go? (which has "," separator between each items)

Comment: Share your go code.

Comment: As @abhink said, show us your non-working Go code if you want us to help you find the bug. We cannot help you if you show us the php code that actually works. Also here's json encoding example in Go https://play.golang.org/p/zsVSujWVLZ.

Comment: @mkopriva special thanks.
in many go examples that i have seen there is no highlight on using string(json.Marhsal(MarshalledResult)), in your example i saw that when using string() explicit cast on marshalled result the comma separators will emerge in result. thanks. the problem solved

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you use json.Marshal the result will be [1 2 3 4] but if you want to use your result as a string and send it to another place like redis , or print on the screen as a valid json, you should explicitly cast your result.

Here are the incorrect and correct codes:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    x := []int64{1, 2, 3, 4}
    y, err := json.Marshal(x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

and the correct code is :
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

```
func main() {
    x := []int64{1, 2, 3, 4}
    y, err := json.Marshal(x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(y))
}
```

Comment: you seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the type conversion in the example, that is there **only** to tell "fmt.Println" how to print the resulting bytes. `json.Marshal` always returns a slice of bytes and if you pass that directly to `fmt.Println` you'll see just the bytes that represent the json. If redis requires a json string then you are right you need to convert the bytes to a string, but if redis requires json bytes then you don't need to convert the result from marshal. https://play.golang.org/p/pJKzAUucQG

Comment: Also take a look at this https://play.golang.org/p/AFQNQkr1dm, you can see that the commas are there without the need of conversion.

Comment: Your first example definitely doesn’t print `[1 2 3 4]`